# Title case in publishing pages

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I just discovered that publishing pages take not only the title from their url, but also the character case!

Example: I have a page called "6.4 - Budget Structure", whose filename is 6.4%20-%20Budget%20Structure.aspx.

If I call this page with this URL

https://xxx.yyy.zzz/sitename/Pages/6.4%20-%20Budget%20Structure.aspx

I get this

[image]

But if I use this url (look at the case!!)

https://xxx.yyy.zzz/sitename/Pages/6.4%20-%20budGet%20structUre.aspx

I get this!!!

[image]

Is there any workaround to avoid it unless rewriting the whole links?

Thanks to all,

Comment: The solution depends on what you want to do with the letters. Is it just the first letter in the title that are supposed to be big?

Comment: I would like the title to mirror the real file name and not the url. In this case (and all other pages) I have the aspx file name with correct case "6.4 - Budget Structure" (of course %20 instead of spaces): I just would like the page not taking the title case from the link url... I hope it is clear.